# Do I need to state full path for "git add a file"

Tags: git

I am new to git.

I made changes to a particular file located here:

```
modified:   resources/views/commission/data.blade.php
```

My question is, how do I push (add) that single file?

Do I do:

```
git add data.blade.php
```

OR

```
git add resources/views/commission/data.blade.php
```

Thanks

Comment: I generally run `git add .` or `git add -u`, depending on many things. The `-u` method is particularly convenient. Note that it does not hurt to re-add an already-added file. (`git push` pushes *commits*, which are full snapshots of all files, regardless of how you add and commit the files. The push protocol is smart and generally omits any bytes that the other Git already has, so that if you added one line to ten files, the push sends about ten lines, even if you are pushing 50 commits with ten thousand files each.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to be in the folder `/resources/views/commission/`, then you may simply `git add data.blade.php` and it will work.  Otherwise, you would need to either give the full relative path to your current location, or give the fully qualified path, starting from root.

So, to summarize:

```
git add /resources/views/commission/data.blade.php
```

should work regardless of your location, and

```
git add data.blade.php
```

should work if you happen to be in the folder which contains this file.

Comment: If you want to add all files that were changed, one could also use `git add .`?

Comment: @ignacio using `git add .` doesn’t always work. Such as if you were in a child folder or sibling folder to the file, such that you would need “../“ to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

While in the folder of the `file`, you can just issue `git add file`.
But if you are not in this `file`'s folder you must use the full path to the file or a relative path from the folder in which you are.

Git status will provide with the relative path, when you execute `git status` in any of your git repository folders.